# PHP preg_match only one match

Tags: php, preg-match

I have had some problems using preg_match, Instead of selecting 1 thing. It finds from the start of the first, to the end of the last.

```
preg_match('/@section\(\'(.*)\'\)(.*)@endsection/s', $content,$results
```

$Content :

```
@section('title')

Number 1

@endsection

@section('content')

Number 2

@endsection
```

But when i use the preg_match, the result comes out like :

```
Number 1

@endsection

@section('content')

Number 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for non-greedy quantifier over here like as

```
/@section\(\'(.*?)\'\)(.*?)@endsection/s
              //^^      ^^
```

[**Regex**](https://regex101.com/r/cU3gY1/1)